# I finished before he/him

Tags: object-complements, subject-complement

> 1. I finished before he
> 2. I finished before him

In formal language, do we use the subject or object pronoun after *before* or *after*?

Comment: Just want to add a bit to Lucian Sava's answer. *Before* can also be used as a conjunction. So "I finished before he did" is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The personal pronoun in question is the object of the preposition before or after. As a result we need to use the object form, that is, **him**:

> I finished before **him**.

Comment: Very true, but we should note that if we use a verb phrase, it becomes *he*: I finished before *he did*.

Comment: Yes indeed, @stangdon, it becomes **he** as the subject of a new sentence.